# Нарисовать прямоугольник по щелчку мыши. JAVA

Tags: java, swing

Есть перегруженное событие клика ЛКМ по фрейму:

```
frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    private DrawRectangle r;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        r = new DrawRectangle(10, 20, 30, 40);
        frame.add(r);
    }
});
```

Есть класс `DrawRectangle`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawRectangle extends JPanel {
    private Rectangle rect;

    public DrawRectangle() {
        rect = new Rectangle();
    }

    public DrawRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        rect = new Rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Color c = new Color(37, 215, 150);
        g2.setColor(c);
        g2.draw(rect);
    }
}
```

Но по клику прямоугольник не рисуется, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вызвать метод `Component.revalidate()` у компонента, на который добавлен новый элемент.

В вашем случае это `frame`:

```
frame.revalidate();
```

Comment: В main'е его нужно вызвать？

Comment: @ArtemAndriukov после добавления `DrawRectangle` на `frame`, в вашем слушателе